# Is there a particular name for this design element?

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, responsive-design

I have seen a lot of magazine/news templates that basically stick a set of posts together and they usually span 2 rows and 3 or more columns.

The best I can think of is maybe calling it a collage, but I was wondering if there was an official/unofficial term for this design.

Here are some screenshots of what I am referring to.

[image]

Another example:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft refers to them as [tiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/app-assets).

These have varying sizes (1x1, 1x2, 2x2, etc), as in your example. The same concept is applied to your display, but using the article images instead of icons.

[image: Start menu tiles]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like masonry style design; where you have different sized images placed next to each other. Pinterest was the first to really run with this design form.

> Masonry is a grid layout based on columns. Unlike other grid layouts, it doesn’t have fixed height rows. Basically, Masonry layout optimizes the use of space inside the web page by reducing any unnecessary gaps. Without this type of layout, certain restrictions are required to maintain the structure of layout.

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-masonry-layout/